# Batch file executing a sound silently

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, mp3, silent

Would it be possible to execute a mp3 silently from batch I have tried:

```
@echo off
1.mp3
pause
```

It works but it doest do it silently it launches WMP. does any one know how I could accomplish this. I am making a program and the track it one of the sound effects.

Comment: You cannot "execute" a batch file any more than you can execute a text file. In both cases, you just instruct an application to read the file and do something with it. So which application would that be in your case?

Comment: I think you misunderstood I need the bat file to play the sound with no output like a program poping up.

Comment: may be you rahter need command line mp3 player ? My first hot from google : http://mpg321.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @09stephenb: No misunderstanding there. I 'm telling you that you need a program to play the mp3. It can't play itself any more than text can display itself or images can draw themselves.

Comment: But what should I use.

Comment: I'd try powershell.  `$PLAYER = New-Object -ComObject 'Mediaplayer.Mediaplayer';
$PLAYER.Filename="C:\1.mp3";
$PLAYER.Play();`  You don't need any program to play MP3 when you have a ComObject.

Comment: wv player is a small command line, and gui, audio player - http://www.webxpace.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Bat/VBS to play an audio file :

```
@echo off
set file=track12.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

Or you can use this small command i wrote in Autoit ([playsound.exe](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9yh04HYXto1U3BzVVJuRTk3dlk/edit?usp=sharing))

Use : playsound.exe "youraudiofile.mp3/wav"