# Executing a command when closing Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskkill

I have a batch file playing a sound in the background while it runs, using the method at [Batch file executing a sound silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259738/batch-file-executing-a-sound-silently) however, when I exit the batch file, the music will continue to play.

Id there any way to run a command while a batch file is closing, so that the sound file will stop playing?

I've tried an example I found called onexit:

```
onexit taskkill /im wmplayer.exe
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just :

```
taskkill /f /im wmplayer.exe
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

First idea i had is another batch:

```
@ECHO OFF
START "" /W <YourBatchhere>
TASKKILL /im "wmplayer.exe"
```

should do the job :)

The `/W` will wait at that point, still YourBatchhere has ended.
Regardless of success or error.

Comment: This would work great except that all batch files names are cmd.exe so this would not close anything as the batch running that code would be open, also It needs to kill wmplayer.exe after the original batch file closes.

Comment: Have you even tested it? You wrote, "when i exit the batch file" - so you must either click "X" - and close the window - or exit your batch in any other way (e.g. typing "exit"). So at that point that "taskkill" will close wmplayer your batch was closed - and it will only close wmplayer.exe as expected.

Comment: Maybe you must clarify your question. if you exit any batch in an "abort-way" the above code does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: It would work, I'll say again, but the Batch file has many labels and it would have to be in just one for the closing

Comment: However, I have now fixed the problem with VBScript